# Python raw_input and conditions

Tags: python, beginner

I have a very simple code that allows me to keep track of what the user inserts in a `raw_input`.

The kind of controls I check are `if the user inserts "f" the program is finished` or `if the user inserts nothing, the program keeps on running remembering all the inputs the user has inserted`.

It works but I think it's very ugly and rudimental.

I would love to get suggestions from experts so I can learn how to handle correctly simple tasks.

Here's the little code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
good_receipts = []
done = False
inserted_text = ''
while not done:
    # This function is os dependent and will work only if you use linux
    os.system('clear')
    inserted_text = raw_input("Insert receipt number (if you finished insert 'f'): ").upper()
    if inserted_text and inserted_text != 'F':
        good_receipts.append(inserted_text)
    while not inserted_text == 'F':
        # This function is os dependent and will work only if you use linux
        os.system('clear')
        if good_receipts:
            print "Here's your receipts:"
            print good_receipts
        if not good_receipts:
            print "You didn't enter a single receipt..."
        inserted_text = raw_input("Insert receipt number (if you finished insert 'f'): ").upper()
        if inserted_text and inserted_text != 'F':
            good_receipts.append(inserted_text)
    done = True
# This function is os dependent and will work only if you use linux
os.system('clear')
print "You did a great job, here's your receipts:"
print good_receipts
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I came up with:

```
#!/usr/bin python
from os import system as sys

def GetReceipt():
    prompt = "Insert receipt number (if you finished insert 'f'): "
    inserted_text = ''
    while True:
        sys('clear')
        inserted_text = raw_input(prompt).upper()
        if inserted_text == 'F': break
        yield inserted_text


def final(receipt):
    sys('clear')
    print ["You did a great job, here's your receipts:\n"+' '.join(receipt), 
        "You did not enter a single receipt..."][len(receipt) == 0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    valid_receipts = [ f for f in GetReceipt() ]
    final(valid_receipts)
```

Comment: `list[bool]` is a useful trick, but in this case I'd say it just makes the code harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

I find it easier to reason about code that actually does something, so I made it display the sum of the inputted numbers.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

try:
    import readline
except ImportError:
    pass

numbers = []
print('Enter your numbers, one per line. Enter "f" when you\'re done.')

while True:
    try:
        inserted_text = input('> ')
    except EOFError:
        print()
        break
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print()
        continue
    if inserted_text.lower() == 'f':
        break
    if not inserted_text:
        continue
    try:
        n = int(inserted_text)
    except ValueError:
        print('That\'s not a valid number.')
        continue
    numbers.append(n)

if numbers:
    print('Here are your numbers and their sum:')
    print(' + '.join(map(str, numbers)), '=', sum(numbers))
else:
    print('You did not enter a single number...')
```

I wrote the code in python3 because there is no reason to be using python2 here.

Importing `readline` improves the usability of the `input` function on platforms that support it.

I kept the possibility of entering "f" to exit, but really most regular console users will just press Ctrl+D, which is handled by the `except EOFError:` clause.

I removed the calls to `clear` because they just annoy the user.

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
good_receipts = []
inserted_text = 'go'
while inserted_text != 'F':
    # This function is os dependent and will work only if you use linux
    os.system('clear')
    inserted_text = raw_input("Insert receipt number "
                  "(if you finished insert 'f'): ").upper()
    if ''!=inserted_text!='F':
        good_receipts.append(inserted_text)
    if good_receipts:
        print "Here's your receipts:\n",good_receipts
    if not good_receipts:
        print "You didn't enter a single receipt..."
# This function is os dependent and will work only if you use linux
os.system('clear')
print "You did a great job, here's your receipts:\n",good_receipts
```